# how to open a website in http form in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, http, wireshark

I am trying to capture packets on Wireshark for a website. But, since safari opens only the https format, Wireshark is not capturing it - it may be seen in TLS but I want to see the http format. How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Many websites, including nytimes.com, redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. You can see this with the Terminal command `curl`, using its `-i` (show header info) option:

```
$ curl -i http://nytimes.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: Varnish
Retry-After: 0
Content-Length: 0
Location: https://www.nytimes.com/
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 01 Jan 2020 20:27:39 GMT
X-Served-By: cache-pao17428-PAO
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Connection: close
X-API-Version: F-0
```

The 301 status and `Location:` header tell the client, essentially, "this isn't the URL you want; go load 'https://www.nytimes.com/' instead". Safari (and other browsers) follow this redirect automatically. If you load "http://nytimes.com" in Safari, you'll see that it's both switched to HTTPS and added "www." to the domain name, because that's what the redirect told it to do.

Also, note that the `Content-Length:` header is 0, and there's nothing but a blank line (that you can't see above) after the header that `curl` printed. That means there's no actual content at the http:// URL. The server doesn't even bother to serve the page content over HTTP, only over HTTPS.

Some servers/domains go even further to require their clients to use HTTPS. Some are configured to serve an [HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), which tells the browser to *never* load anything from that domain over HTTP, but always auto-switch to HTTPS instead. They can also register for HSTS preload, which tells browser developers to include an HSTS policy for the domain without needing to hit the server to get it. nytimes.com doesn't do this, but you can use [this site](https://hstspreload.com) to check other domains. Here's a check on `google.com`:

```
$ curl https://hstspreload.com/api/v1/status/google.com
{"domain":"google.com","chrome":{"present":true,"include_subdomains":true,"last_updated":1577844002},"firefox":null,"tor":null}
```

...which says it's included in Chrome's preload list, but not Firefox's or Tor's. AIUI Safari uses Chrome's list, so google.com should always be auto-switched to HTTPS in Safari.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! But I don't think it helped me....let me rephrase the problem: "I Installed Wireshark on Mac OS. I am trying to capture packets of a website like nytimes.com but since the website opens as https, therefore, Wireshark is not capturing the packets of this website. Can we capture packets of a website on Mac OS using Wireshark?"

Comment: @mayankturan You should be able to capture the redirect with Wireshark (if Safari is auto-redirecting, use the `curl` command I gave), or you can capture the encrypted HTTPS session. You cannot capture the website's actual contents in an unencrypted form, because the server refuses to send them unencrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not related to the browser. Many websites will automatically redirect http traffic to https to insure a secure connection.

If you apply the following display filter

```
http.response.code == 301
```

You will notice that the webserver is redirecting to the secure https endpoint.

[Wireshark capture for http://nytimes.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbKZw.png)

If you want to experiment with a website that will not auto-redirect you to https, I suggest using

```
http://example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to Safari > Preferences.
2. Click the Advanced tab.
3. Check the "Show full website address" box.
4. Close the Preferences window.

**And now you can see the full URL in Safari.**

Comment: I want to open website like nytimes.com in http format. it is opening in https format.

Comment: You cannot open it in HTTP format it will automatically redirect you to the HTTPS version of the site.